# Получение ширины и высоты для JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Пытаюсь добится того, чтобы дочерний элемент нарисовал рамку с небольшим отступом от края окна, но получить размер окна в случае когда он задается через setExtendedState() не получается. Может быть есть более удачная альтернатива?

```
public class MainProc extends JFrame
{

    MainProc()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        System.out.print("Height: " + this.getHeight() + " Width: " + this.getWidth());

        Area gArea = new Area();
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(this.getHeight() - 10, this.getWidth() - 10);

        gArea.setPreferredSize(dim);
        add(gArea);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        new MainProc();

    }

}


class Area extends JLabel
{
    Area()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, просто рамка, внутри поле для построения графики. Задачу поставил получить рамку которая при открытии на любом ПК давала бы максимальный размер экрана минус небольшой отступ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это решение немного проще и более гибкое

```
public class MainProc extends JFrame {
    MainProc() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(
                new CompoundBorder(
                        new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10),
                        new LineBorder(Color.black, 1)
                )
        );
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // остальные компоненты добавляйте в panel

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        new MainProc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант я нашел чтобы решить задачу, на мой взгляд он не самый удачный, пускай он и решает задачу.

```
public class MainProc extends JFrame
{

    MainProc()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        System.out.print("Height: " + this.getHeight() + " Width: " + this.getWidth());

        Area gArea = new Area();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        dim.height -= 30;
        dim.width -= 10;

        gArea.setPreferredSize(dim);
        add(gArea);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        new MainProc();

    }

}


class Area extends JLabel
{
    Area()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }
}
```

Comment: Михаил, подскажите, во что заключить код, чтобы также удобно и красиво его публиковать? Извиняюсь за офтоп.

Comment: при редактировании обратите внимание на панель инструментов редактора. там есть кнопка **{}** вот она и оформляет код. так же вы можете почитать документацию по этому сайту. в шапке есть ссылка на "справка"

Comment: Спасибо @Mikhail, буду пользоваться, думаю что вопрос не последний, как тут часто бывает.